# Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In AD connect FOREST is not listed and also when I try to enter the domain manually I am getting  **"The domain specified in the credentials does not exist or cannot be contacted. Using credentials with a fully qualified domain may help to resolve this issue. Learn more"**

[image]

Comment: It was resolved we need to create a local forest first it will automatically it was showing Thanks

Comment: Kindly update your answer in the "Answer" section.